# If a light bulb is connected to different voltages, is there a single method to calculate the utilized power?

Tags: electricity, electric-current, potential, power

If a bulb is marked at 100W and 200V, we know that the bulb utilises a power of 100W when connected to a 200V potential difference. So, can we say that the bulb, when connected to twice the potential difference the bulb utilises a power of X watts?

Answer (score 0):

The type of diagram that measures this behaviour is called [Current-voltage characteristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current%E2%80%93voltage_characteristic).

There is actually no single formula because with increasing voltage, the filament inside the light bulb heats up which increases the resistance. This is different for every type of lamp, so **you'd need to do an experiment** and measure the current for different voltages with your particular light bulb. This curve usually looks approximately like this (it's a screenshot from one of the videos below):

[image: Screenshot from https://youtu.be/2kclj3vc1EI?t=483]

The wattage is easily calculated then by reading the amperage from the plot at the corresponding voltage and then multiplying them, i.e. $P=U\cdot I$

Actually, a quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Current%E2%80%93voltage+characteristic+light+bulb) reveals that measuring this quantity seems to be a widespread educational experiment, I particularly liked [this source](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251567174_Voltage-Current_Characteristic_of_Incandescent_Lightbulbs_Measurement_and_Analysis) which states that the characteristic has the general form

$$I=a\cdot U^b$$

and after measuring different bulbs (up to 12 V), they end up with different values of $a$, but $b$ stays within the range $0.5<b<0.56$.

There are also some nice videos, e.g [this one](https://youtu.be/UIxBKfnG1co?t=164) explains some theory and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kclj3vc1EI) does the exact experiment.